# Conditional Probability - Cancelling the numerator with denominator...

Tags: probability

If this question has been answered somewhere else, I apologize, and welcome the redirection.

I've been given the formula for conditional probability (the probability of event A happening, given event B) as: $$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(B)}$$

My question is if $P(A\text{ and }B) = P(A) * P(B)$ then wouldn't the probability of event B just cancel each other out in the numerator and denominator?

In my head, I know this can't be right, so I think I must have made a mistake when finding the probability of (A and B) but I'm not sure where I went wrong...or what formula I should be using instead.

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if P(A and B)=P(A)∗P(B)  then wouldn't the probability of event B just cancel each other out in the numerator and denominator?

Yes, but only *if* that were the case.   It isn't always so.   The product rule only applies in the case of **independent** events.   Not all events are independent; that's *why* we have conditional probabilities.

> or what formula I should be using instead.

That entirely depends on what you have been given to work with.   What are your events?   What is the experiment/model?   Do you know $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$?   And so forth.

If you have the former two you should be able to evaluate $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ from first principles.   If you have the latter, you can use: $\;\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf P(A)\;\mathsf P(B\mid A)\;$.

You may already have encountered **Bayes' Rule**, or maybe you will soon be introduced to it.

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A)\;\mathsf P(B\mid A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$

Answer (score 4):

$P(A \text{ and }B)=P(A)P(B)$ if and only if the events $A$ and $B$ are *independent.* For instance, consider flipping a coin, and let $A$ be the event that it lands on heads, and let $B$ be the event that it lands on tails. Clearly $P(A \text{ and }B)=0$, but $P(A)P(B)=1/4$.